# Why does dplyr::case_when break when trying to reference column name from setNames

Tags: r, dplyr, case-when

This is my first question on StackOverflow. I'm doing my best to create the reproducible example below, but please tell me if something isn't quite right. I've seen enough newbies get flamed to death, so I'm hoping this is OK.

I'm trying to write a function that will return a single value from rows containing TRUE-FALSE values, using dplyr::case_when. Everything works beautifully if I hard code the column names, but break whenever I try to reference the name from somewhere else as it returns it as a string. I've been working for hours on this and I must be missing something simple.

I tried using assign, get, and eval(parse)) without success. Also tried through a list without success.

```
xcol1 <- c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
xcol2 <- c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
xcol3 <- c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)
xcol4 <- c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)
xcol5 <- c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)
ycol1 <- c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
ycol2 <- c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
ycol3 <- c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)
ycol4 <- c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)
ycol5 <- c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)

data <- data.frame(xcol1, xcol2, xcol3, xcol4, xcol5, ycol1, ycol2, ycol3, ycol4, ycol5)

colSelect <- "xcol"

names <- setNames(paste0(colSelect, seq(1, 7)), seq(1, 7))

#Works when column names are hard coded
cols <- select(data, contains(colSelect)) %>%
  mutate(bad_good = case_when(
    xcol1 == TRUE ~ 1,
    xcol2 == TRUE ~ 2,
    xcol3 == TRUE ~ 3,
    xcol4 == TRUE ~ 4,
    xcol5 == TRUE ~ 5
  )
  )

#Doesn't work when column names are referenced from a subset 
cols2 <- select(data, contains(colSelect)) %>%
  mutate(bad_good = case_when(
    names[[1]] == TRUE ~ 1,
    names[[2]] == TRUE ~ 2,
    names[[3]] == TRUE ~ 3,
    names[[4]] == TRUE ~ 4,
    names[[5]] == TRUE ~ 5
  )
  )
```

I need to be able to use case_when to output a single column from multiple columns of TRUE-FALSE values, with the name of those columns being customizable from the colSelect variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap `names[[x]]` in `sym()` and then evaluate it using `!!`. You can learn more by google searching *"Programming in Dplyr"*

```r
library(tidyverse)

colSelect1 <- "xcol"

names1 <- setNames(paste0(colSelect1, seq(1, 7)), seq(1, 7))

cols1 <- select(data, contains(colSelect1)) %>%
    mutate_all(as.logical) %>% 
    mutate(bad_good = case_when(
        !!sym(names1[[1]]) ~ 1,
        !!sym(names1[[2]])  ~ 2,
        !!sym(names1[[3]])  ~ 3,
        !!sym(names1[[4]]) ~ 4,
        !!sym(names1[[5]]) ~ 5,
    )
    )

cols1
#>   xcol1 xcol2 xcol3 xcol4 xcol5 bad_good
#> 1  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE        1
#> 2 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE        2
#> 3 FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE        3
#> 4 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE        4
#> 5 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE        5

colSelect2 <- "ycol"

names2 <- setNames(paste0(colSelect2, seq(1, 7)), seq(1, 7))

cols2 <- select(data, contains(colSelect2)) %>%
    mutate_all(as.logical) %>% 
    mutate(bad_good = case_when(
        !!sym(names2[[1]]) ~ 1,
        !!sym(names2[[2]])  ~ 2,
        !!sym(names2[[3]])  ~ 3,
        !!sym(names2[[4]]) ~ 4,
        !!sym(names2[[5]]) ~ 5,
    )
    )

cols2
#>   ycol1 ycol2 ycol3 ycol4 ycol5 bad_good
#> 1  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE        1
#> 2 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE        2
#> 3 FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE        3
#> 4 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE        4
#> 5 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE        5
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! This works beautifully, and helps me understand how R evaluates objects inside functions. I wasn't aware how quotation worked in dplyr. I found these resources with your Google Search suggestion, that I'll be sure to study thoroughly.
http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/328769_e8a0152e155b4163b4a54473adcea229.html
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeAllard No problem, it might be worth combining this all into a function that takes `colSelect` as an input so you can reduce your code and make it reusable.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly my objective with this question! 

Might I ask why you added mutate_all(as.logical) to the pipe? I tried it with and without, and it seems to output the same result.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeAllard, I think you can disregard that line, when I was playing with your data, I think at some point the `TRUE/FALSE` values got converted to character so I changed them back. As an aside, I was going to mention, that since your values are already bool you can change `!!sym(names[[x]]) == TRUE` to `!!sym(names[[x]])` because `case_when()` will always look for a bool on LHS of the `~` so no need to compare again. You may already know that, some people opt for the first option because it's more explicit when reading through it.

Comment: Right. I thought it was about adding robustness in case it was fed characters instead of booleans. I didn't know about LHS boolean evaluation, that's good to know!